# Visualizing GeoTIFF containing multiple GeoTIFF data sources (APPEND_SUBDATASET) in QGIS

Tags: geotiff-tiff

I have a GeoTIFF that I have created in the following manner:

```
gdal_translate first_grid supergrid.tif

gdal_translate second_grid supergrid.tif -co APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES
```

Dragging this into QGIS appears to only allow me to visualize the first dataset used.  Is there some option to allow me to view all added datasets?  This does seem to work if I use a GeoPackage instead of a GeoTIFF.

I can use software like Teledyne Caris BASE Editor to successfully view the datasets within the supergrid GeoTIFF, so I'm wondering if I am just missing something in QGIS.

Comment: Have you considered using VRT's? They work really well in qgis both for visualisation and analysis. See link: https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html

Comment: It seems that QGIS is missing a support for subdatasets in GeoTIFF. Write mail to qgis-users list and ask. But that is very uncommon way to use TIFF pages. Normally in geotiff the additional pages are used for overviews. With subdataset approach other pages are used for different images. And since GDAL 3.2 there an option for advanced tagging "this page is the n:th overview of the subdataset B". Don't be surprised if there is issues with interoperability.

Comment: I have looked at VRTs, but what I need is something that will work with PROJ vgridshift and allow me to provide one file for several different resolution TIFFs.  If that makes sense.  The TIFF subdatasets do allow me to do this in PROJ.  So I will go ahead and ask in qgis-users about support for TIFF pages.  Thanks.